# SharePoint 2013 Attachments

Tags: 2013, list-view, attachments

Can you attach multiple attachments to a list. I know you can in 2010

Answer (score 1):

Attaching multiple files individually (you cannot upload multiple files) then yes, you can do this in 2013 list
[image]

Comment: I cannot open what you attached. Im sorry for asking so many question

Comment: As such I didn't attach anything here. I included an picture which shows two or multiple files can be attached to a list.  Please let me know if you want me to add anything more to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I could at it at one time or if I had to add one file or attachment at at ime